# Is it possible for the Simpson's method to converge faster than Rombergs method?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I have the following integral:
$\int_{0}^{100} \frac{x^{3/2}}{\cosh{(x)}}dx$

I am running code for the Simpson's method and Romberg method to evaluate the integral numerically and the results show that the error of the Simpsons method decreases and converges faster than Romberg's method. But I thought that Romberg's method always converged faster. The difference is not extreme, but it is significant enough to warrant some confusion.

Details:
I ran both algorithms using 2,4,16,...,1024 sub-intervals.
The results were as follows

At $2^{10} $sub-intervals:

Simpsons rule: 4.58814722721e-05

Rombergs rule: 0.000154030460427

Comment: Please show more details : Number of iterations, number of partial intervals used etc.

Comment: I have added a few more details, let me know if anything is still unclear.

Comment: It can be due to a mistake in the extrapolation procedure, you're then stuck with an error term that you don't get rid off.

Comment: I have used code from http://modelling3e4.connectmv.com/wiki/Numerical_differentiation_and_integration and I have checked over it I do not think there is a mistake in this extrapolation and I used wikipedias algorithm for Simpsons method

Comment: I think you may have used too large a step size for the first few  subdivisions, the extrapolation method then doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you think so? Note that the integrand gets really small really fast so i think thats why the first 2 steps in Romberg are the same. I don't know if this is wrong?

Comment: Any clues as to why this is happening?

Comment: 1) error estimate of quadrature methods assume that the integrands is sufficiently smooth. However $x^{3/2}$ is only $C^1$, which breaks the most higher order estimation. 2) Rombergs rule is only 3 times as bad as Simpsons. nothing to worry about

Comment: As an aside, $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{2k}}{\cosh x}~dx~=~a_k~\bigg(\frac\pi2\bigg)^{2k+1},~$ where $a_k$ is the sequence described [here](http://oeis.org/A000364).

Comment: Also, $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{2k+1}}{\cosh x}~dx~=~2(2k+1)!~\beta(2k+2).~$ See [Dirichlet $\beta$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function) for more information.

Comment: @Lucian how exactly is your comment connected to the question?